# JS regex: replace all digits in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all digits.

My function only replaces the first digit.

```
var s = "04.07.2012";
alert(s.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]"), "X")); // returns "X4.07.2012"
                                            // should be XX.XX.XXXX"
```

Comment: I think you need the global replace option. And `[0-9]` can be simplified to `\d`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need to add the "global" flag to your regex:

```
s.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", "g"), "X")
```

or, perhaps prettier, using the built-in literal regexp syntax:

```
.replace(/[0-9]/g, "X")
```

Comment: How would I replaced them with a unicode character instead of `X`?  For instance `\U2022` ?

Comment: answer: `replace(/[0-9]/g, '\u2022');`

Comment: This works only if string has all digits. Doesn't work with "test123"

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
s.replace(/\d/g, "X")
```

which will replace all occurrences. The `g` means *global match* and thus will not stop matching after the first occurrence.

Or to stay with your `RegExp` constructor:

```
s.replace(new RegExp("\\d", "g"), "X")
```

Answer (score 6):

find the numbers and then replaced with strings which specified. It is achieved by two methods

1. Using a regular expression literal
2. Using keyword RegExp object

**Using a regular expression literal:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var string = "my contact number is 9545554545. my age is 27.";
alert(string.replace(/\d+/g, "XXX"));

</script>
```

**Output:**my contact number is XXX. my age is XXX.

**for more details:**

http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-replace-number-with-string-in-JavaScript/1156

Answer (score 4):

*The* `/g` *modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first)*

*You can use* `\d` *for digit, as it is shorter than* `[0-9]`*.*

***JavaScript:***

```
var s = "04.07.2012"; 
echo(s.replace(/\d/g, "X"));
```

***Output:***

```
XX.XX.XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the global operator. Use this:

```js
var s = "04.07.2012";
alert(s.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]","g"), "X"));
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the accepted answer?