# Replace using Regular Expression - fixed digit location

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I would like to replace from a number of 16 digits, it's 5th to 10th digit.

How can that be achieved with a regular expression (C#)?

Comment: A non-regex solution would probably be better here, since your dealing with digit positions.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328353/js-regex-replace-all-digits-in-string

Comment: How about you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: @DGibbs: You want to see his "guess?"

Comment: Regular Expressions are incredibly powerful, but they should not be used as the solution every single time you need to manipulate some text. Often other ways are easier less processing intensive.

Comment: Why not just pluck out the digits you want to replace and create a new value from it? Regular expressions seems like unnecessary overkill.

Comment: I got something like.... d{4}d{5}d{6} which i need to replace d{5} with  * ... trying to figure out the syntax

Comment: @RobertHarvey An attempt at solving the problem himself would be a good start.

Comment: @DGibbs: OK.  But check your close reasons.  It's not too broad, it's not unclear, it's not primarily opinion-based, and it's not an incomplete request for troubleshooting.

Comment: posted my solution below

Comment: 16 digit number which you want to mask with `*`, sounds suspiciously like a credit card number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is to capture in the inner and outer portions separately, like this:

```cs
 // Split into 2 groups of 5 digits and 1 of 6
 string regex = "(\\d{5})(\\d{5})(\\d{6})";

 // Insert ABCDEF in the middle of 
 // match 1 and match 3
 string replaceRegex = "${1}ABCDE${3}";

 string testString = "1234567890999999";

 string result = Regex.Replace(testString, regex, replaceRegex);

 // result = '12345ABCDE999999'
```

Comment: As an aside, the first line would read a tiny bit better like this: `string regex = @"(\d{5})(\d{5})(\d{6})";`

Comment: Its compact as you are declaring everything inline ;-)

Comment: @DavidG: I was going to type that just now, but thought this was albeit a bit more verbose, clearer in what I was trying to show. I could do a one liner ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why use a regular expression? If by "number of 16 digits", you mean a 16 character long string representation of a number, then you'd probably be better off just using substring.

```
string input = "0000567890000000"; 
var output = input.Substring(0, 4) + "222222" + input.Substring(10, 6);
```

Or did you mean you want to swap the 5th and 10th digits? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression `(?<=^\d{4})\d{6}(?=\d{6}$)` to achieve it without capture groups.

It looks for 6 consecutive digits (5th to 10th inclusively) that are preceded by the first 4 digits and the last 6 digits of the string.

```
Regex.Replace("1234567890123456", @"(?<=^\d{4})\d{6}(?=\d{6}$)", "replacement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it... 
by creating 3 capturing groups:

```
([\d]{5})([\d]{5})([\d]{6})
```

keep capturing group1 and 3 and replace group2 with stars (or whatever)

```
$1*****$3
```

C# code below

```
string resultString = null;
try {
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"([\d]{5})([\d]{5})([\d]{6})", "$1*****$2", RegexOptions.Singleline);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
// Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Notice that you are using 4 + 5 + 6 = 15 characters, not 16 as per your original question

Comment: this is the solution i just put together from regex buddy.

Comment: explained more above, and updated with 16 characters, my fault on the typo.

Comment: Isn't that what I proposed as a solution? Why ignore casing? ;-)

Comment: you are right, removed it. Marked yours as a solution.

Comment: @piris: RegexBuddy is good, but try RegexMagic (http://www.regexmagic.com/) for this sort of work. You know what you want, and RegexMagic finds you the Regular Expression to match it.