# Replace an expression in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that has some numbers in the middle of the string.

For example,

```
var str = "abcd-123456.com"
```

I want to remove the numbers like this

```
abcd.com
```

I am not trying to replace all numbers.
I have to replace only `-*.` expression with `""`.
How do I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: It is possible. You can use a regular expressions.

Comment: You could have tried to find this FAQ first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS regex: replace all digits in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328353/js-regex-replace-all-digits-in-string)

Comment: i do not want to remove all digits. only wants the digits between - and . only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "abcd-123456.com"    
str = str.replace(/-[0-9]*/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

**AS PER YOUR COMMENT**

The answer of Shivaji Varma will *nearly* do the tricks.

```js
var str = "abc5d-123456.c0om"  
str = str.replace(/-[0-9]*./g, "")
console.log(str)
```

Soooo,

- Using the slash indicate a regular expression.
- [0-9] indicate you want to replace all digit between 0 and 9 (included)
- "*" to remove all digits
- "-" and "." to delimite

Comment: Raising the post at same time, and just to show other solution he may use.

I flagged the post, but I think people need to know **why** they are doing something useless.

Comment: what if i wants to remove - and . too?

Comment: str = str.replace(/-[0-9]*./g, "") seems to work. answer updated !

Answer (score 0):

Your comments lead me to believe you want

```js
var str = "abcd-123456.com";
var str1 = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("-"))+str.substring(str.indexOf("."))
console.log(str1);

//or with regex
  
// dasah plus 6 digits to nothing
var str2 = str.replace(/-\d{6}/,"")
console.log(str2);

// dash, digits and an dot to dot
var str3 = str.replace(/-\d+\./,".")
console.log(str3);
```