# Prevent text box from enter numeric value, accept only text with minimum 50 characters using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  one text box that should accept only text not numeric values ,with some additional requirement.

```
1) I need minimum 50 characters.
2) Extra space replace with single space
3) Only take text and remove only numbers if type
```

Below code is not working for requirement of "not to accept numbers" but for other requirement it is working fine.

```
<textarea  
        id="chq_not_submit_reason" 
        class="textarea_rec"
        onblur="validate($(this).val())"
        placeholder="Please Enter your comments here"
></textarea>
```

JS

```
function validate(val) {
    if (val.match(/[^A-Za-z'. .]/g)) {
        val = val.replace(/[^A-Za-z'. .]/g, '');    // not allow numbers if enter numeric value erase only numbers not text
    }

    if (val === '') {
        $(".show_err").html('<p style="color:red;">Don\'t leave this field blank</p>');
    } else if (val.replace(/\s/g, "").length < 50) { // allow single space  with minimum 50 characters
        $(".show_err").html('<p style="color:red;">Minimum 50 characters required</p>');
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS regex: replace all digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328353/js-regex-replace-all-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#chq_not_submit_reason').on('keyup', handleOnKeyup);

function handleOnKeyup() {
  $(this).val(
    $(this).val()
      .replace(/\d/g, '') // Removes numeric characters
      .replace(/ +/g, ' ') // Replaces multispaces by single space
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="chq_not_submit_reason" class="textarea_rec" placeholder="Please Enter your comments here" maxlength="50" ></textarea>
<div class="show_err"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#chq_not_submit_reason').on('keyup', handleOnKeyup);
$('#chq_not_submit_reason').on('blur', handleOnBlur);

function handleOnKeyup() {
  $(this).val(
    $(this).val()
      .replace(/\d/g, '') // Removes numeric characters
      .replace(/ +/g, ' ') // Replaces multispaces by single space
  );
}

function handleOnBlur() {
  if ($(this).val().length < 50) {
    $('.show_err').html(`<p style="color:red;">Minimum 50 characters required.</p>`);
  } else {
    $('.show_err').html('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="chq_not_submit_reason" class="textarea_rec" placeholder="Please Enter your comments here" minlength="50" ></textarea>
<div class="show_err"></div>
```